# Qt include windows.h error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token }

Tags: c++, windows, qt

My application was compiling correctly but suddenly, after minor code changes, it started to give this error.

In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winbase.h:40:0,
from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:70,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qt_windows.h:64,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtGui/qopengl.h:49,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtQuick/qsggeometry.h:44,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtQuick/qsgnode.h:43,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtQuick/qsgrendererinterface.h:43,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtQuick/qquickwindow.h:44,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtQuick/qquickview.h:43,
from C:\Qt\5.12.12\mingw73_64\include/QtQuick/QQuickView:1,
from qtquick2applicationviewer\qtquick2applicationviewer.h:14,
from qtquick2applicationviewer\qtquick2applicationviewer.cpp:11:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/utilapiset.h:28:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token
}
^

I checked my code and i could not find anything strange. It seems something related to windows.h.

So i tried to create a new project from QtCreator. I created a Qt Quick application and i only add the inclusion of windows.h

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

and it is also giving this error

C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\utilapiset.h:28: error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token
In file included from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/winbase.h:40:0,
from C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:70,
from ..\ProvaWindows\main.cpp:1:
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw730_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/utilapiset.h:28:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token
}
^

I can't understand why it suddendly stop compiling.

NOTE: I'm having this error using MinGW 7.3.0 64 bit, if i change compiler and for example i use the same MinGW 7.3.0 but 32 bit, i have no errors!

Please help!
Thanks

Comment: I question why you are including `windows.h`. As a Qt developer on windows at work since 2008 I find it extremely rare to need to include `windows.h` directly.

Comment: Hi! In the real project on which i'm working on is necessary. The example that i posted here is only to show that i have this error also in an application created from zero from Qt Creator. I tried this to have a confirm that the error is not related to something else in the real project

Comment: @drescherjm let me explain better..in the real project i'm not including windows.h directly, but it is included for example by QtCore/qt_windows.h. I'm going to change the post to make it clearer.

Comment: Ifound that the file utilapiset.h had something wrong inside it (i don't know how and who had modified it). I fixed it and not it works!